# how to use a svg matrix transform to scale only not to translate (implicite)?

Tags: matrix, svg

I am fighting with svg matrix

what i want is to scale the size of an object, not its origin (in the drawing), ie. make it smaller (or bigger) but dont move it

i have a box x=y=w=h=4 and an other

```
X---####----####
----####----####
----####----####
----####----####
```

i want x=4=y=4 w=h=2

```
X---##------##
--------------
----##------##
--------------
```

what ever I try i get (without useless things)

h=y=w=h=2 (ie. scale a half)

```
X-##--##
--##--##
```

notice, that i dont know the origin at the line of "scale" to half size

my math isnt that bad but my vector-math was small and is long ago

**edit: fiddle**
(oh, to late)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9QU2/)

Comment: I'd put the example with a bit of code/markup on a jsfiddle first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, scaling is a 4-step process:

step 1 - get element's center via its bounding box

step 2 - translate the element so the center is at the origin(0,0)

step 3 - scale it

step 4 - translate the element back to its original position

When dealing with SVG matrices and transforms it is a good idea to use a
**Matrix Transform Request Object** and attach the element to be transformed to a **Transform List Object**.  Initially this may not be as intuitive as using transform strings. i.e. "translate(-100,-200)scale(2,2)translate(100,200)"

However, in the long run it will serve you well.

Below is an example of the Object driven transforms

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style='font-family:arial'>
<center>
(This example tested in: IE11/CH31/FF23)
<div style='width:90%;background-color:gainsboro;text-align:justify;padding:10px;border-radius:8px;'>
Sequentially Transform an element about a fixed 'center point' in the element.
For this example, use the initial center of its bounding box.
</div>
<div id="svgDiv" style='background-color:lightblue;width:400px;height:400px;'>
<svg id="mySVG" width="400" height="400">
<rect id="myBox" fill="red" x=100 y=100 width=100 height=100 />
<circle id=centerPoint r=10 fill=lime />
</svg>
</div>
<button onClick=rotate()>rotate</button>
<button onClick=scaleXY()>scaleXY</button>
<button onClick=skewX()>skewX</button>
<button onClick=skewY()>skewY</button>
<button onClick=startOver()>start over</button>
 <br />SVG Source:<br />
<textarea id=svgSourceValue style='font-size:110%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:200px'></textarea>
</center>
</body>
<script>
document.addEventListener("onload",init(),false)
function init()
{
    initTransform()
    svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
}

var Cx,Cy
var TransformRequestObj
var TransformList
//---onload---
function initTransform()
{
    var bb=myBox.getBBox()
    var bbx=bb.x
    var bby=bb.y
    var bbw=bb.width
    var bbh=bb.height
    Cx=bbx+.5*bbw
    Cy=bby+.5*bbh
    centerPoint.setAttribute("cx",Cx)
    centerPoint.setAttribute("cy",Cy)
    SVGPnt=mySVG.createSVGPoint()

    TransformRequestObj=mySVG.createSVGTransform()
    var animTransformList=myBox.transform
    TransformList=animTransformList.baseVal
}
//--button--
function rotate()
{
    var angle=30

    TransformRequestObj.setRotate(10,Cx,Cy)
    TransformList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransformList.consolidate()

    svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
}
//---button---
function scaleXY()
{
    var scaleX=1.05
    var scaleY=1.05

    TransformRequestObj.setTranslate(Cx,Cy)
    TransformList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransformList.consolidate()
    TransformRequestObj.setScale(scaleX,scaleY)
    TransformList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransformList.consolidate()
    TransformRequestObj.setTranslate(-Cx,-Cy)
    TransformList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransformList.consolidate()

    svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML

}
//---button---
function skewX()
{
    var skwX=5 //---radians

    TransformRequestObj.setTranslate(Cx,Cy)
    TransformList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransformList.consolidate()

    TransformRequestObj.setSkewX(skwX)
    TransformList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransformList.consolidate()

    TransformRequestObj.setTranslate(-Cx,-Cy)
    TransformList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransformList.consolidate()

   svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
}
//---button---
function skewY()
{
    var skwY=10 //---deg
    TransformRequestObj.setTranslate(Cx,Cy)
    TransformList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransformList.consolidate()

    TransformRequestObj.setSkewY(skwY)
    TransformList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransformList.consolidate()

    TransformRequestObj.setTranslate(-Cx,-Cy)
    TransformList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransformList.consolidate()

    svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
}
//---button---
function startOver()
{
    myBox.removeAttribute("transform")
    TransformRequestObj=mySVG.createSVGTransform()
    var animTransformList=myBox.transform
    TransformList=animTransformList.baseVal
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I take this answer, its a good hint, thx, the point is, I can't trnsform without the knowdelege of the original position. Yes and how should that be pssible? (I go back to school sitting there a few hours :-))