# Find centre of svg path elements

Tags: javascript, svg

Hello I am fairly new with svg and JavaScript and I am trying to make some svg elements popup (by scaling) when the mouse is over the svg and vice versa when the mouse is off the svg element.

I have been able to make the svg element increase in size by using transformation, but is there a way that they scale from their center's?

Here is my svg (I created it using this website [svg-edit](https://svg-edit.github.io/svgedit/dist/editor/index.html)):

```js
 // event-driven mouse-interaction with SVG objects
        
        function unselected_colour(evt) {
            // get the element that triggered the browser event
            let target = evt.target;
            // modify the element
            target.setAttribute('transform', 'scale(1)')
        }
        function selected_colour(evt) {
            // get the element that triggered the browser event
            let target = evt.target;
            // modify the element
            target.setAttribute('transform', 'scale(1.25)')
        }


        // find the SVG rectangle in the DOM
        let mileEndRoad_obj = document.getElementById('mile_end_road');
        let bandcroftRoad_obj = document.getElementById('bandcroft_road');

        let godwardSquare_obj = document.getElementById('godward_sqaure');

        let compSci_obj = document.getElementById('computer_science');
        let itl_obj = document.getElementById('itl');
        let engineering_obj = document.getElementById('engineering');
        let peoplePalace_obj = document.getElementById('people_palace');
        
        // pass the above functions as callbacks, to be triggered by mouse events
        godwardSquare_obj.addEventListener('mouseover', selected_colour, false);
        godwardSquare_obj.addEventListener('mouseout', unselected_colour, false);

        compSci_obj.addEventListener('mouseover', selected_colour, false);
        compSci_obj.addEventListener('mouseout', unselected_colour, false);

        itl_obj.addEventListener('mouseover', selected_colour, false);
        itl_obj.addEventListener('mouseout', unselected_colour, false);
        
        engineering_obj.addEventListener('mouseover', selected_colour, false);
        engineering_obj.addEventListener('mouseout', unselected_colour, false);

        peoplePalace_obj.addEventListener('mouseover', selected_colour, false);
        peoplePalace_obj.addEventListener('mouseout', unselected_colour, false);
```

```html
  <svg width="1640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <!-- Created with SVG-edit - https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit-->
        <g class="layer">
         <title>map</title>
         <path d="m38,86.66667l0,94l64.66666,0l0.00001,-28l8.66666,0l0,27.33333l35.33334,0l-11.33334,-20l-12.66666,0l-0.00001,-8c8,0 12.66667,0 12.66667,0c0,0 -0.66667,-65.33333 0,-65.33333c0.66667,0 -89.33333,0 -97.33333,0z" 
         fill="rgb(94,43,126)" id="computer_science" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5"/>

         <rect fill="#10a3a3" height="447.44527" id="bandcroft_road" stroke="#10a3a3" stroke-width="5" width="35.76642" x="308.90512" y="-24.52553"/>
         <rect fill="#10a3a3" height="54.74453" id="mile_end_road" stroke="#10a3a3" stroke-width="5" width="647.44528" x="-1.31387" y="425.10952"/>

         <path d="m239.41174,257.50001l-133.52938,-0.14706l-0.00001,-69.85294l50.7353,-0.00001l-16.17647,-31.61765l58.82353,0l0,30.14706l39.70588,0l0.44115,71.4706z" 
         fill="#1bd1a6" id="godward_sqaure" stroke="#1bd1a6" stroke-width="5"/>

         <rect fill="rgb(94,43,126)" height="100.5" id="itl" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5" width="65" x="37" y="192"/>

         <path d="m174.99947,274.5c-0.33149,41.16667 0.33149,82.83333 0,124l290.39161,0l0,-11.5l69.138332,0l0,-37l-68.641082,0l0,-142.5l-101.93541,0l0,167.5l-73.09515,0l0,-101l-115.8583,0.5z" 
         fill="rgb(94,43,126)" id="engineering" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5"/>

         <path d="m534.99996,206.029419l70.147082,-0.147072c0,0 0.441155,35.441191 -0.294139,34.705896c-0.735294,-0.735294 33.088235,0.000001 32.64708,-0.147072c-0.441155,-0.147073 0.441156,39.852955 0,39.705882c-0.441155,-0.147073 -18.676491,0.147074 -19.117647,0c-0.441156,-0.147073 0.441155,116.323546 0,116.176471c-0.441155,-0.147076 -82.647081,0.882369 -83.088235,0.735294c-0.441154,-0.147076 -0.294141,-191.764693 -0.294141,-191.029399z" 
         fill="rgb(94,43,126)" id="people_palace" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

If any further explanation please let me know.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: You keep using the svg.js tag even though you are not using svg.js. Please only use this tag if you are actually using svg.js. Thanks :)

Comment: oh okay sorry, i thought svg.js meant a combination of svg and javascript. I will make sure not to write this in the future thank you

Comment: No problem. You can actually hover the tag to get more information. And who knows, maybe svg.js would resolve your problem as well. It's a good library :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the center with getBBox

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox

Then scale with a matrix

- [how to use a svg matrix transform to scale only not to translate (implicite)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563321/how-to-use-a-svg-matrix-transform-to-scale-only-not-to-translate-implicite)

Comment: hi, I'm a bit confused about what to do once I've define new objects using getBBox, could you help me out?

Comment: You use ``getBBox`` to **get** the boundaries of an **existing** element; then you calculate its center, and take those coordinates into the matrix.

Comment: im confused by the matrix part, I don't understand how to do it. I've calculated the center using getBBox but the matrix part doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Yes, the Matrix part is not just copy-paste; You have to learn and understand WHAT it does: https://www.google.com/search?q=svg+matrix+center+scale

Comment: okay thank you for your help, i appreciate it